# DEM elevations not appearing when rendered to single band pseudocolor

Tags: qgis, dem, rendering

When rendering DEM file to single-band pseudocolor, the elevation values are not appearing. Attached are images of the proper template and my layer properties. Please let me know what other data would be helpful.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be well defined. Include a screenshot of the layer tree expanded and the map canvas after you accept those layer properties.

Comment: Did you press Apply?

Comment: Yes, I applied it and it only showed the minimum and maximum elevation points. I did not display the multiple elevation values shown in the second image. I am following along in a workbook and it is defined correctly. I attached images after I applied it and what it is supposed to look like. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? And in which OS? Have you tried to change the classification mode from *Continous* to *Quantile*?

Comment: @BenMill , Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuVYd.png a screenshot of your layer symbology property or a screenshot of the workbook? How do your layer symbology look? https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpCgF.jpg seems to be a previous state, there are not defined a color ramp nor the classes of the symbology.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, i.stack.imgur.com/FuVYd.png is an image of the workbook. So, i.stack.imgur.com/IpCgF.jpg is of a previous state. The corrected state still shows essentially the same color ramp and classes of symbology as that image. I will upload the new current state I am working with to the original post now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ValP I am using 3.10 LTR. Per the workbook I am using, this is meant to be a continuous color ramp, not quantile. I still did try switching, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you have edited the color ramp, removing its classes and defining two new ones. Since then, your layer symbology has two classes and that is what you see in the layers tree, and that is how the layer is rendered, with a continuous linear interpolation between both classes.

To modify it, you need to define new classes in the symbology, by pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> button. You can click on the color to edit it, in the Value field to associate that class to a value, and in the Label field to show the label of that class in the layers tree.

If you want to start again from the color ramp that you have selected (seems to be Schwarzwald one), just press the <kbd>Classify</kbd> button.

Also, be sure to read the documentation section for the [Singleband Pseudocolor](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#singleband-pseudocolor) symbology property.

Comment: Adding the elevation individually did work! Thanks!